# How to run automated test using css Selector Appium java

Tags: java, android, css, webview, appium

I am trying to make an automated testing using Appium in java language. However, to access the elements I use the webview on browser to find using css Selector. My question is how to switch to webview using Appium in java language? I found that appium support selenium and can use `driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW")` but the fact its not. Now I use this code I found on the internet but when I run the script, TestNG didn't show anything failed or succeed or skipped and the application on the device just open then close. Any help?
PS: I changed com.xxx.xxx to myApps for this forum.

```
    package com.android.test;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

    import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

    public class Login2 {
        public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

        @BeforeTest
        public void before() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
              DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
              capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "192.168.150.101:5555");
              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.0");
              capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
              capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "myApps");
              capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "myApps");
              driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              Set<String> availableContexts = driver.getContextHandles();
                System.out.println("Total No of Context Found After we reach to WebView = "+ availableContexts.size());
                for(String context : availableContexts) {
                    if(context.contains("WEBVIEW")){
                        System.out.println("Context Name is " + context);
                        // 4.3 Call context() method with the id of the context you want to access and change it to WEBVIEW_1
                        //(This puts Appium session into a mode where all commands are interpreted as being intended for automating the web view)
                        driver.context(context);
                        break;
                            }
                        }
        }

        @Test
        public void login() throws InterruptedException{
            //Thread.sleep(6000);
            WebElement log = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ng-click^='logReg']"));
            log.click();
            driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
        }

        @AfterTest
        public void after(){
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

This is the element I'm trying to choose to be clicked

```
    <div class="background-menu col box-menu loginIcon" ng-click="logReg()">
        <img class="menu_icon3" src="img/MenuIcon/blank.png" alt="login">
    </div>
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can You post output from Appium console ? Probably Your app has `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` set to`false`. Make sure your app has it enabled, otherwise You won't have WebView context.

Comment: Anyway, I found another way to switch to the webview, you know the answer for this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452767/cannot-start-a-selendroid-session-because-the-server-apk-does-not-exist) thank you so much. How can I check if the app has set it true or false? Because I didn't make it, I'm just testing it. thank you.

Comment: You can check it in Appium Inspector. There is a "Context" menu under properties of selected element (check screenshot - http://imgur.com/a/RoFZy ). If there is `WebView` , Your app has WebView debugging enabled. Otherwise, You need to ask developer to include it in app.

Comment: I'm using Appium for Windows and there is no context at the inspector. Is there anyway to see that in Appium for Windows or have to use Mac? Thank you.

Comment: Part of Your method should store available contexts `Set<String> availableContexts = driver.getContextHandles();
                System.out.println("Total No of Context Found After we reach to WebView = "+ availableContexts.size());` . You can iterate through this set and check if there is a 'WEBVIEW` context or only native one. For testing purpose, You can inert Thread.sleep(time) for app to load.

Comment: I did use that and it printed 2 which consist of WEBVIEW and NATIVE_APP. but now I get an WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: can you take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518284/unknown-server-side-error-occurred-while-processing-the-command) Although it was a bit different because I found an example from the appium website itself. Thank you.